# Algorithm to repeatedly pseudorandomly select from a set, without frequent repeats

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, combinatorics

I have an array of things (conceptually a set, but let's implement as an array), say [A, B, C, D, E, F].

I need an algorithm that can pseudo-randomly pick an item from the array such that no item will be picked twice within x iterations.

That is, if x is 3 for this array, this would be ok: F, C, B, D, F, E, A, B,...

This would not be ok: F, C, D, C, ...

Other than this constraint, the selections should be as random as possible. (For instance, simply shuffling the array and selecting within copies of it is not acceptable.)

Ideally, this would achieved without having to record all the previous picks.

So the function would have a structure like:

```
function pick(options, minspacing, iteration) {...}
```

Comment: You want a vector you can delete from arbitrarily. Set your upper limit to the vector length. Select randomly from the range, remove the item, and append it to the end. Decrement the upper limit for the first x times, then don't decrement again. I can assume x is less than the length, otherwise you'd run out of items to select before x is up.

Comment: I guess for Javascript you'd use an array, and `splice()` to remove and `pop()` to append the element.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to fit the bill:

For each iteration `i`, if `i<x`, then:

- randomly choose an index `j` in [i,N)
- if `i!=j`, then swap `A[i]` with `A[j]`
- return `A[i]`

For all other iterations, where `i>=x`:

- randomly choose an index `j` in [x, N)
- swap `A[j]` with `A[i%x]`
- return `A[i%x]`.  It will not be swapped back into the choosable range until after `x` more iterations.

```js
function pick(options, minspacing, iteration) {
    if (iteration < minspacing) {
         const j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(options.length - iteration)) + iteration;
        const t = options[j];
        options[j] = options[iteration];
        options[iteration] = t;
        return t;
    } else {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(options.length - minspacing)) + minspacing;
        const i = iteration % minspacing;
        const t = options[j];
        options[j] = options[i];
        options[i] = t;
        return t;
    }
}

const opts = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const results = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(i => pick(opts, 3, i));
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first step chose in [x, N), so the elements currently in the first x positions are never selected, as they hold the x elements that were picked last?

Comment: yes. Typo.  Fixed, thanks.

Comment: You could unify the two cases if you select `j` from `[min(i, x), N)`, right? Also, a bit of explanation would be great, dividing the array into two regions where each selected element is swapped into the ignored region and then swapped back exactly x iterations later...

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I think cleaner than supplying an iteration number, would be to take the set of options and the minimum spacing and return a *function* that keeps track of the current state and can always return you an appropriate next choice.  Here's one implementation:

```js
const randomNotRecent = (arr, n) => ((xs = [...arr], c = 0) => () => (
  (r) => (xs.push(r), r)
)(xs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (xs.length - Math.min(c++, n))), 1)[0]))()

const pick = randomNotRecent(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 3)
  
console.log(Array(25).fill(0).map(pick).join(' '))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This is written in my usual expressions-not-statements style.  In this case, that ends up relatively dense.  An alternate version of the same idea would be something like this:

```js
const randomNotRecent = (arr, n) => {
  const xs = [...arr]
  let c = 0
  return () => {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (xs.length - c))
    c = Math.min(c + 1, n)
    const r = xs.splice(i, 1)[0]
    xs.push(r)
    return r
  }
}
```

(**Update**: switched the update of `c` with the assignment of `i`; the original version would never have picked the last item in the collection on the first iteration.)

As in other answers here, we randomly select an element from the first (length - spacing) elements, remove it from the array and push it to the end.  We make initial copy of the array so that we don't mutate the original data, and we use a counter parameter (`c`) to track our initial progress until we've hit min-spacing.

Then `pick = randomNotRecent(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 3)` is a function with a closure containing a slowly shuffling copy of the original array and an integer counter that increments until it reaches `3` and stays there.  You can use it continually to choose a next element.

Answer (score 0):

This code choses a pseudo-random index from a range >=2 without replacement up to an arbitrary non-repetition length >=1 . You can then use the index to dereference any array of values of the same length [A,B,C ... ].

```
var max_choice = 10; // >= 2
var replacement_limit = 3; // >= 1 

let chosen = new Array(replacement_limit);

function chose() {
  let choice;
  do {
    choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_choice);
  } while (chosen.includes(choice));
  if (chosen.length == replacement_limit) {
    chosen.pop();
  }
  chosen.unshift(choice);
  return choice;
}

let runs = 20
for (let i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
  console.log(chose());
}
```

Incorporating this as a closure you have a generator of unlimited choice iterations.

```
var options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var replacementLimit = 3; // >= 1 and <options.length

function pick(options, minSpacing) {
  let chosen = new Array(minSpacing);
  return function chose() {
    let choice;
    do {
      choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
    } while (chosen.includes(choice));
    if (chosen.length == minSpacing) {
      chosen.pop();
    }
    chosen.unshift(choice);
    return options[choice];
  }
}

let iteration = 20;
generateChoice = pick(options, replacementLimit);
for (let i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
  console.log(generateChoice());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to handle this problem (as per my understanding of the problem) would be like:

**Pseudocode:**

```
1. Init: 
        Set s; for keeping track of recently picked items.
        counter; for keeping track of number of iterations.
        result; for storing result.
2. while counter < iteration:
      2.1. Pick a random item from the options array
      2.2. if item is not in s:
           2.2.1. If the size of s === len(options):
                  2.2.1.1. clear s.
           2.2.2. Add it to set and add the pick to result.
           2.2.3. Increment the counter.
      2.3. If item in s, but we haven't reached the minimum spacing,
          2.3.1. continue to pick a new item.
      2.4. If item in s, and we've reached the minimum spacing,
           2.4.1. Remove it from the set and continue to pick a new item.
```

**CODE IMplementation:**

```js
function pick(options, minspacing, iteration) {
  const s = new Set();
  let counter = 0;
  let result = "";
  while (counter < iteration) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
    const item = options[index];

    if (!s.has(item)) {
      if (s.size === options.length) {
        s.clear();
      }
      result += `${item} `;
      s.add(item);
      counter++;
    } else if (counter % minspacing !== 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      s.delete(item);
      continue;
    }
  }
  return result.trim();
}
const options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
console.log(pick(options, 3, 10));
```

Hope it helps.